Real Time Telegram Message Storer
Well, so basically what I am trying to do is capture and store the messages posted on a SPECIFIC Telegram Group/Channel, live, in real-time. I have gone through the documentations, tried writing the code myself, but it does not work. The program just keeps executing without any output. Can anybody help me with the correct code?? I'd also like to know how to implement this system for private channels.
import asyncio
from telethon import TelegramClient,events
from datetime import datetime
# Replace these with your own values
api_id = '226671'
api_hash = '7610eaa49ddtyr546dcfa47d7f46434'
channel_username = 'FOREXSIGNALXAUUSDONE'
client = TelegramClient('session_1', api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats='FOREXSIGNALXAUUSDONE'))
async def main(event):
    print('{}'.format(event))
client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()

I hope you guys can figure this out. Also this is my first time on StackExchange, so please excuse any mistakes. Thanks!

I highly recommend you to not leak your api credentials

Well thanks for your concern, @Apepenkov ! I changed my credentials before posting it though.

Reding the doc you need to use the client.start() instance result as the main client
import asyncio
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
from datetime import datetime

# Replace these with your own values
api_id = '226671'
api_hash = '7610eaa49ddtyr546dcfa47d7f46434'
channel_username = 'FOREXSIGNALXAUUSDONE'

# Initialize the Telegram client
client = TelegramClient('session_1', api_id, api_hash).start()

# Define an event handler for new messages in the specified channel
@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=channel_username))
async def new_message_handler(event):
    # Print the message content
    print(f"New message received: {event.text}")

try:
    print('(Press Ctrl+C to stop this)')
    client.run_until_disconnected()
finally:
    client.disconnect()


[Running] python -u "e:\tempCodeRunnerFile.py"
[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.464 seconds
No output.. The program ran and stopped executing instantaneously.
Maybe the client.run_until_disconnected() should be put somewhere else??

indeed need to use the TelegramClient instance resulting from.start() method

RuntimeError: coroutine ignored GeneratorExit           What does this mean??I got this error after running the updated code. Is it a memory related error??
